# Parent-child tracking of string and removing duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, string, parent-child

I'm trying to turn my list of strings in python, from this output:

```
  interface Ethernet1/24
-   channel-group 4000 mode active
  interface Ethernet1/46
-   channel-group 4001 mode active
  interface Ethernet1/24
+   channel-group 4000
  interface Ethernet1/46
+   channel-group 4001
```

Expected output:

```
  interface Ethernet1/24
-   channel-group 4000 mode active
+   channel-group 4000
  interface Ethernet1/46
-   channel-group 4001 mode active
+   channel-group 4001
```

Originally I thought I could just remove the duplicates in the list, but then I have the order to keep track of so simply removing the duplicates would not work in this case.